# Service for 'youtrack' does not exists in Hub

Tags: docker, kubernetes, youtrack

Running Youtrack on Rancher RKE (Docker container).
The volume got an issue that needed a fix (fsck), so I fixed it which all went well (?).
After restarting Youtrack, I can not get it to work anymore.
I never rebooted it at all before this time, so not sure if the 'fix' is causing this

Running: jetbrains/youtrack:2021.3.24402

```
Starting YouTrack...
* Configuring JetBrains YouTrack 2021.3
* JetBrains YouTrack 2021.3 runtime environment is successfully configured
* Loading logging configuration from /opt/youtrack/lib/ext/log4j.xml
* Redirecting JetBrains YouTrack 2021.3 logging to /opt/youtrack/logs/internal/services/bundleProcess
* Configuring Service-Container[bundleProcess]
* Configuring Bundle Backend Service
* Configuring Starting Page Service
* Configuring YouTrack Configurator
* Configuring Hub
* Configuring Bundle Hub Configurator
* Configuring YouTrack
* Starting Service-Container[bundleProcess]
* Starting Bundle Backend Service
* Starting Starting Page Service
* JetBrains YouTrack 2021.3 will be available on [https://support.XXXXX(redacted).com/bundle/starting] after start
* Starting YouTrack Configurator
* Starting Hub
Initializing Hub log folder: /opt/youtrack/logs/hub
gflogger:  version 20131206
* Starting Bundle Hub Configurator
[YouTrack Error] [2021-10-09 16:30:23,252]  ERROR - dle.util.hub.HubServiceUpdater - Cannot update services information in Hub
[YouTrack Error] com.jetbrains.bundle.util.hub.UpdaterHubServiceException: Service for 'youtrack' does not exists in Hub (http://127.0.0.1:8080/hub). Attempt to create it failed: HTTP 400 Bad Request Details: YouTrack should have license
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.util.hub.HubServiceUpdater.ensureCreatedAndVerified(HubServiceUpdater.java:142) ~[bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.util.hub.HubServiceUpdater.update(HubServiceUpdater.java:59) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.services.impl.HubConfiguratorService.configureHubServices(HubConfiguratorService.java:87) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.services.impl.HubConfiguratorService.doStart(HubConfiguratorService.java:64) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.services.impl.ServiceBase.start(ServiceBase.java:66) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.Services.startService(Services.java:648) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.Services.startAllServices(Services.java:575) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.Services.start(Services.java:555) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.BundleMain.start(BundleMain.java:273) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.BundleMain.start(BundleMain.java:237) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.bootstrap.Bundle$EntryPointProvider$1.invoke(Bundle.java:100) [bundle-bootstrap-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.start(Unknown Source) [?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.launcher.AppProxy$6$1.call(AppProxy.java:99) [youtrack-wrapper.jar:1.0.131]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.launcher.AppProxy$6$1.call(AppProxy.java:97) [youtrack-wrapper.jar:1.0.131]
[YouTrack Error]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
[YouTrack Error] Caused by: javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:999) ~[jersey-client-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:816) ~[jersey-client-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92) ~[jersey-client-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:700) ~[jersey-client-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[jersey-common-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[jersey-common-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228) ~[jersey-common-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444) ~[jersey-common-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:696) ~[jersey-client-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:448) ~[jersey-client-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:349) ~[jersey-client-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at jetbrains.jetpass.client.accounts.ServiceClient.createService(ServiceClient.java:38) ~[hub-client-all-2018.1.8679.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.hub_client.util.HubUtil.createEmptyVerifiedService(HubUtil.java:114) ~[hub-client-util-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.util.hub.HubServiceUpdater.ensureCreatedAndVerified(HubServiceUpdater.java:126) ~[bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    ... 21 more
[YouTrack Error] [2021-10-09 16:30:23,466]  ERROR - es.impl.HubConfiguratorService - Service does not exists in Hub. Check property youtrack.service.id in file conf/internal/hub.properties
[YouTrack Error]  Problem: Service for 'youtrack' does not exists in Hub (http://127.0.0.1:8080/hub). Attempt to create it failed: HTTP 400 Bad Request Details: YouTrack should have license
[YouTrack Error] com.jetbrains.bundle.util.hub.UpdaterHubServiceException: Service for 'youtrack' does not exists in Hub (http://127.0.0.1:8080/hub). Attempt to create it failed: HTTP 400 Bad Request Details: YouTrack should have license
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.util.hub.HubServiceUpdater.ensureCreatedAndVerified(HubServiceUpdater.java:142) ~[bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.util.hub.HubServiceUpdater.update(HubServiceUpdater.java:59) ~[bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.services.impl.HubConfiguratorService.configureHubServices(HubConfiguratorService.java:87) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.services.impl.HubConfiguratorService.doStart(HubConfiguratorService.java:64) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.services.impl.ServiceBase.start(ServiceBase.java:66) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.Services.startService(Services.java:648) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.Services.startAllServices(Services.java:575) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.Services.start(Services.java:555) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.BundleMain.start(BundleMain.java:273) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.BundleMain.start(BundleMain.java:237) [bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.bootstrap.Bundle$EntryPointProvider$1.invoke(Bundle.java:100) [bundle-bootstrap-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.start(Unknown Source) [?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.launcher.AppProxy$6$1.call(AppProxy.java:99) [youtrack-wrapper.jar:1.0.131]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.launcher.AppProxy$6$1.call(AppProxy.java:97) [youtrack-wrapper.jar:1.0.131]
* Error while starting JetBrains YouTrack 2021.3: Service for 'youtrack' does not exists in Hub (http://127.0.0.1:8080/hub). Attempt to create it failed: HTTP 400 Bad Request Details: YouTrack should have license
[YouTrack Error]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
[YouTrack Error] Caused by: javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:999) ~[jersey-client-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:816) ~[jersey-client-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92) ~[jersey-client-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:700) ~[jersey-client-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[jersey-common-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[jersey-common-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228) ~[jersey-common-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444) ~[jersey-common-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:696) ~[jersey-client-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:448) ~[jersey-client-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:349) ~[jersey-client-2.20.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at jetbrains.jetpass.client.accounts.ServiceClient.createService(ServiceClient.java:38) ~[hub-client-all-2018.1.8679.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.hub_client.util.HubUtil.createEmptyVerifiedService(HubUtil.java:114) ~[hub-client-util-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    at com.jetbrains.bundle.util.hub.HubServiceUpdater.ensureCreatedAndVerified(HubServiceUpdater.java:126) ~[bundle-1.5.637.jar:?]
[YouTrack Error]    ... 21 more
[YouTrack Error] [2021-10-09 16:30:23,472]  ERROR -                 bundle.startup - Error while starting JetBrains YouTrack 2021.3: Service for 'youtrack' does not exists in Hub (http://127.0.0.1:8080/hub). Attempt to create it failed: HTTP 400 Bad Request Details: YouTrack should have license
* Stopping YouTrack
* Stopping Bundle Hub Configurator
* Stopping Hub
* Stopping YouTrack Configurator
* Stopping Starting Page Service
* Stopping Bundle Backend Service
* Stopping Service-Container[bundleProcess]
YouTrack process finished
Launcher is exiting
```

There is a youtrack service and a loadbalancer, it might be the `127.0.0.1` needing to be `0.0.0.0`

Checked the volumes, they all seem ok. Running out of options to try.

Comment: Could you please share the start command used?

Comment: @skoch13 it is a docker container, the start is done by the `run.sh` included in the youtrack container. it is just using all the defaults, no start command given in k8s.

Comment: I guess that might be the case, please start it as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/youtrack-docker-installation.html)

Comment: on a side note, it looks like a volume mapping issue or running of fsck somehow broke the volume that includes `conf` folder